# CatchyTech, affiliate spammer

Tags: discussion, spam

I just stripped something like 30 affiliate links, all to the same hosting company, out of [this user's](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/2490/catchytech) 32 answers so far, almost all of which consist of something along the lines of "Arvixe is a very good hosting." and not much more. This has been going on since last October. He's also been doing it [over on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/452699/catchytech), though less comprehensively. Figured it'd be easier all around to call it out here than go on a flagging spree.

Comment: Well spotted. I saw at least one of them, but didn't spot that there were so many.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I noticed the arvixe.com links but not the affiliate links - apparently spammer was editing older posts to add affiliate links.

In any case, the issue has been addressed here at Pro Webmasters and I've flagged ten of the similar affiliate links over at SO.

Comment: ok, I double checked using http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Farvixe.com%22